# Different ways to describe Hilbert's Hotel

Tags: set-theory

In math, Hilbert's Hotel (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) is a famous paradox that describes a situation where a hotel with infinitely many rooms and full capacity somehow has the ability to still accommodate more guests.

I have always found this concept difficult to understand and often resort to the following explanation:

- How many numbers are there between 3 and 1? An infinite number of numbers (e.g. 1.1, 1.111, 1.1111....2.1, 2.1111, etc.)
- How many numbers are there between 2 and 1? Also an infinite number of numbers
- Yet we all know that the space between  (3-1) > (2-1)
- This is the paradox: from one angle, a number appears to be significantly smaller than another number - yet it is still somehow possible to construct equally sized intervals around these numbers and then pack an infinite quantity of numbers within these intervals

Is my interpretation of Hilbert's Hotel correct?

Note: I don't actually understand how this paradox was resolved. Supposedly a concept of "Cardinality" was created to measure the relative sizes of these infinities and thus reconcile the paradox.

Comment: Hilbert's hotel is enumerable, at least the versions I've read. The idea is, for example, put 1 extra guest in by shifting everyone 1 room down. Or an infinite number of guests in by putting each guest in room $2n$ to free up an infinite number of odd rooms. Or sticking an infinite number of infinite collections of guests in by devising a scheme where no one is left out. Vilenkin reproduces the story in some of his books on infinity.

Comment: @ robin: thank you for your reply! I will check out this book. Is my summary of this correct?

Comment: These examples are illustrations of standard ways to show that the cardinality of the natural numbers is also the cardinality of the integers and the rationals. The cardinality of reals is greater, not enumerable, and you use different arguments to prove that. Hilbert's hotel is not about the reals.

Comment: To answer your comment question - no, your interpretation is off. The point of the hotel illustration is that the rooms have numbers, you can count them (forever). You can't, even in principle, count the reals on any interval, whereas you could in principle count the rationals.

Comment: There's a nice animation on the subject here: https://www.tiktok.com/@veritasium/video/7333294752533695790 .

Comment: For a complete version of the story, check out "Stories about Sets" by N. Ya Vilenkin. It will show you the difference between some infinities in a gentle way. He also has "In Search of Infinity", which includes the story too, but is a bit more advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key to understanding Hilbert's Hotel is the idea of "countable infinity". In intuitive terms, a set is countably infinite if it is the "same size" as the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.

---

How do we determine if two sets are the same size, especially infinite ones? Let's start with finite sets and see if we can work our way up to infinite sets. For example, let's examine the sets A = {1,2,3,4}, B = {5,6,7,8}, and C = {9,10,11}. We're using numbers here because it's easier, but remember sets can contain anything. Now, intuitively it feels like A and B are the same size (4, to be exact), but C is a different size.

But how do we show this? Let's "pair up" the elements of A and B. 1 and 5 pair up, 2 and 6 pair up, 3 and 7 pair up, and 4 and 8 pair up. Since we can build this pairing (in mathematics, we'd call it a "mapping" or a "map") in a way that every element of A is paired with *exactly one* element of B, and every element of B is paired with *exactly one* element of A, we then say that this mapping is *one-to-one* or *bijective*. Because we have this bijective mapping, we can feel comfortable saying that A and B are "the same size" - the math term is that they have the "same cardinality".

Let's try to find a bijective mapping from A to C. 1 pairs with 9, 2 pairs with 10, 3 pairs with 11, and 4 pairs with...??? We *can't* find a bijective mapping from A to C, since one element of A is always going to be missing a pair. Then, we can say that A and C have different cardinalities.

---

Alright, so we have an intuition (pairings) and a mathematical method (bijective maps) for comparing the sizes (which we now call cardinalities) of sets. Let's see if we can generalize this to infinite sets.

Let's look at the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the set of even natural numbers $\mathbb{E} = \{2,4,6,\ldots\}$. Now, it may seem like there have to be "less" even numbers than natural numbers - after all, the natural numbers include the even numbers! This intuition is correct when we're talking about finite sets, but things tend to be wackier with infinite sets.

In fact, these two sets can be said to have the same cardinality! Say we pair each number in $\mathbb{N}$ with double itself in $\mathbb{E}$. This means that 1 pairs with 2, 2 pairs with 4, 3 pairs with 6, and so on. This mapping is bijective (one-to-one), and so we can say that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{E}$ have the same cardinality. Mathematically, we'd write that $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{E}|$. (As a nice exercise, try to design the bijective mapping between $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and the set of odd numbers (call them $\mathbb{O} = \{1,3,5,\ldots\}$). What's the formula that can create our pairs?)

---

With countable infinity under our belt, we can talk about Hilbert's Hotel. Say we have a hotel with a (countably) infinite number of rooms, all full, but we want to accommodate a (countably) infinite number of new guests. To do this, we shift every guest to the room with the room number double their current one (1 goes to 2, 2 goes to 4, and so on). This is effectively utilizing the fact that $|\mathbb{N}| = |\mathbb{E}|$, since we can "fit" all the infinite guests into just the even numbered rooms. However, this then leaves all the (countably infinite) odd numbered rooms open to welcome more guests.

You might be able to see how we could use this method to accommodate two more buses. First, shift everyone in the hotel to the room with the room number three times their current room number, so 1 goes to 3, 2 goes to 6, and so on. Then, one countably infinite bus can drop its passengers into the rooms numbered one more than a multiple of 3 (1, 4, 7, 10, and so on) and the other one can drop its passengers into the rooms numbered two more than a multiple of 3 (2, 5, 8, 11, and so on). The Hotel problem also includes methods to accommodate infinite buses.

---

It can be also shown that the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers, is countably infinite. However, I should note that there are infinities even "bigger" than countable infinity. For instance, $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers (rational numbers and irrational numbers), can be shown to have a larger cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$. For understanding why, I'd recommend investigating [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument). There's also a [fantastic animated YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzuMSJTysmg&ab_channel=Josh%27sChannel) (with a talking dog) that goes into this in a whole lot more depth and explains some more of the terminology (as well as the aforementioned diagonal argument). It also explains how we can always create infinite sets with larger and larger cardinalities. I love this video and I'd really advise taking a look. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Issac Cheng: thank you so much for your answer! Do you think my interpretation was correct?

Comment: @firstpassage I think you're on the right track. The key idea, though, isn't that the amount of real numbers between 1 and 3 is bigger than the amount of real numbers between 1 and 2. In some ways, in fact, it's more beautiful. The idea is that any infinite set (say, the reals between 1 and 3) can be broken into two infinite sets (the reals between 1 and 2, as well as the reals between 2 and 3) that are *exactly the same size* as the original set. Also, on a somewhat pedantic detail - the reals between 1 and 3 are *uncountably* infinite, actually larger than the Hotel's countable infinity.

Comment: I should add - I'm not sure whether *any* infinite set can be broken up easily into two infinite partitions, but the natural numbers (1,2,3,...) and any interval of the real numbers ( (1,2), [2,3), [1,3], etc) can using arithmetic and inequalities.